# Is it considered readable to call methods inside the IF condition?

Tags: c#, java, coding-style

Is this way of writing IF conditions considered good coding style in Java and C# languages or not?

```
if (checkIfIdInFirstRange()){
    //call Range1 handling method
}else if(checkIfIdInSecondRange()){
    //call Range2 handling method
}else{
    //call error handling method
}
```

I'm wondering about the method inside the IF condition itself, or would it be better to make it like:

```
int idInRange = getIdInRange();
//handle isInRange
```

Comment: Since methods can return boolean values anyway, why not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is fine.

Even better is if you phrase your methods like a question, or flows with the if statement

```
if (thisConditionIsTrue()){
    // Do this
}elseif(anotherConditionIsTrue()){
    // Do this instead
}elseif(isThisParameterOkay(someParameter)){
    // Yeh do this
}
```

Some hardcore purists will even say that if you have > 3 levels of indentation, your method is too nested and should be split into smaller methods.

Comment: Good point! Regarding to the example in the question, I suggest to use functions like `bool isIdInFirstRange()` and `bool isIdInSecondRange()`.

Comment: Should read more about the healthy number of indentation levels, I try to always make my code maintainable as much as possible.

Comment: @medopal I think it is fine as long as the method called is just checking for some condition. But if the method is doing some important logic for the application, it is not good at all.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this is IMHO good coding practice **as long as** the method calls don't have any side effects.

e.g.

if `checkIfIdInFirstRange()` this is OK:

```
private bool checkIfIdInFirstRange()
{
  return firstRange.Contains(ID);
}
```

But doing this might create confusion:

```
private bool checkIfIdInFirstRange()
{
  SomeStringProperty = "totally new value that no caller would ever expect after a call to this method";

  return firstRange.Contains(ID);
}
```

---

Another possible solution - depending on the actual type of your problem at hand - could be to define an interface / base class and use polymorphism.

**example:**

```
internal abstract class A
{
  public void DoSomething(int ID)
  { 
     if(IsInRange(ID))
       DoSomethingProtected(ID);
  }

  protected abstract bool IsInRange(int ID);

  protected abstract void DoSomethingProtected(int ID);
}


internal class B : A
{
  private List<int> firstRange = new List<int> { 42, 23, 5};
  protected override bool IsInRange(int ID)
  {
     return firstRange.Contains(ID); 
  }
  protected override void DoSomethingProtected(int ID)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", ID);
  } 
}


public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     B foo = new B();
     foo.DoSomething(3);
     foo.DoSomething(42);
  }
}
```

CAUTION: code written without IDE to hand.

Comment: Side-effects in a predicate method are generally a bad thing.  But if the name of the method makes it clear that it is NOT a pure predicate, then this shouldn't be too much of a problem for the reader.  For instance, a method called 'tryToMove' ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It would be much more readable if you used just a little whitespace. Bunching it up like that makes it hard to tell where things begin and end and makes `else if()` look like a function call.

```
if ( checkIfIdInFirstRange() ) {
    //call Range1 handling method
} 
else if ( checkIfIdInSecondRange() ) {
    //call Range2 handling method
}
else {
    //call error handling method
}
```

Making the extra variable is likely to make code harder to read since you have to define them all before the if/else stack. However, it all depends on the case. Sometimes it might be better to use a variable if you will be using an expensive function many times or if you can make the variable have a more descriptive name than the function.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is also required if you want to test multiple methods and use short-circuit evaluation.

For instance, this is safe:

```
if (isResourceAvailable() && isResourceValid()) {
    ...
}
```

while this may no be:

```
bool resAvailable = isResourceAvailable();
bool resValid = isResourceValid(); // can you call that alone?

if (resAvailable  && resValid ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like a very good place to use Short-Circuiting here, but in this specific case, I would put the isAvailable inside the isValid, but I got your point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is good style as long as the methods you call don't just do something that would be clearer if it was coded in place:

```
if ( a > 0 && a < 10 ) doSomething();
```

is better than

```
if ( isInRange(a, 0, 10) ) doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Eh, it's mostly up to the coder but declaring the int is a bit more readable.

Comment: It's always up to the coder, but I was asking if it's considered readable by *other* coders.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to write methods in the IF condition statement. But if the method will be used more than one time, you should first use a local variable to store the return value and use the variable as the IF condition

Answer (score 0):

You can aim at writing function / method names that will make the code more readable where they are used. Like:

```
if (idInFirstRange()){
    //call Range1 handling method
}else if(idInSecondRange()){
    //call Range2 handling method
}else{
```

Also, usual convention for functions returning bool is that they start with `is` - `isIdInFirstRange`

Lastly, try avoiding such if-else ( and switch ) ladder. Try to use Dictionaries in such cases. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506340/if-if-else-or-switch-case/6506403#6506403 )

Answer (score 0):

Although this practice is not wrong or condemned by any best practices guidelines, if you have more than one call within *if **condition*** it can be a bit difficult to know which call refused to enter *if **statement*** during a debug session.

```
if (idInFirstRange() && idInSecondRange()){
    //call Range handling method
    //if didn't reach this point, who was the responsible (idInFirstRange or idInSecondRange)? 
}else if(idInSecondRange()){
    //call Range2 handling method
}else{
    //call something else
}
```